# WinCE 6.0 device not responding to ping

Tags: windows-mobile, windows-ce, activesync, tcp

i am working on WinCE 6.0(On ARM9) based (Headless)Device. 
i established a ethernet(EMACB1) connection between My Desktop(XP-SP3) and WinCE Device.
the device shows network established but wince device not respong to ping.

Below are my TCP/IP Settings:

```
Desktop:
IP Address:       192.168.1.176
SubnetMask:       255.255.255.0
Default Gateway : 192.168.1.1

WinCE Device:
IP Address:       192.168.1.21
SubnetMask:       255.255.255.0
Default Gateway : 192.168.1.1
```

and i had set same primery and Alternative DNS for both.

My aim is to collect any data from the WinCE device. 
As Activesync is not secured (No Authentication), I wish to use Ethernet(TCPIP) Connection.

What am I missing?

also i have some doubts:
1) is NIC mondatory for TCPIP? as i am not using any NICs.
2) is there any way to give authorization for Activesync.
3) which protocol is better to communicate locally between PC and WinCE Device(Headless) over ethernet.(Like VPN or TFTP or TCPIP etc)

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Thanks in Advance
rocky

Answer (score 1):

Your Linksys router at `192.168.1.1` could be blocking ActiveSync.

Also, make sure the USB connections in settings are set to ActiveSync (enable advanced network functionality), and not Mass Storage.

Here are some notes copied over from [PocketPC FAQ](http://www.pocketpcfaq.com/pocketpc.com/syncethernet.htm): (re-posted here in case the website goes away)

You must follow a few preliminary steps before loading new components for Ethernet.

- Establish a serial cable, infrared, or USB connection to the PC with which you are going to use ActiveSync. This is required to put the PC's computer name in your Pocket PC for use with Ethernet.
- Install the Ethernet drivers from the Ethernet vendor's installation disk. This will add a Network Control Panel as well as other relevant files. This installation requires less than 250 kilobytes of free memory for storage. You may also use the built-in NE-2000 drivers if you prefer to save the storage space.
- Reset the device to load the new components.

Next, configure the Network Control Panel for Ethernet on your Pocket PC.

- Click Start.
- Click Settings.
- Click Network.

[image: Fig 1]

*Figure 1: Example of the TCP/IP Properties for Socket's Low Power Ethernet CF+ Card.*

- Enter the IP address for the Pocket PC. I suggest the TCP/IP address 192.168.1.2 with subnet mask 255.255.255.0, and the WINS server address, which is the PC's IP address (192.168.1.1 using my recommended setting).
- Leave the other fields blank.

[image]

*Figure 2: Properly configured Network Control Panel settings on the Pocket PC.*

**Connecting**

- Plug both the Pocket PC and the PC into the hub. (If you are using a crossover cable, you can connect the Pocket PC and PC directly without a hub.)
- Turn on the PC and the Pocket PC and plug the Ethernet PC card into your Pocket PC.
- To start an ActiveSync session, select **ActiveSync** on your Pocket PC (choose **Start**, then **Programs**, and then **Connections**). Make sure the Method is set to **Network Connection** and the **Connect To** matches the PC computer's name. Then click **Connect** to start ActiveSync communications.

If you enable continuous ActiveSync synchronization, your Pocket PC will stay up-to-date, downloading new e-mail, tasks, contacts, and other files and data whenever it's connected to your desktop PC.

**Gotcha**

After plugging your Ethernet PC card into your Pocket PC, check for a link light on the PC's Ethernet card. If it is not lit, you are having a cable or hub problem.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your Replay, I am Able to connect the PC using Active sync Over USB but I am trying to Connect TCP/IP Over Ethernet(EMACB1 without ActiveSync). I tried above mentioned configuration with EMACB1 in ControlPanel- NetworkSettings - EMACB1 But I am not able to communicate.                                                               I am Using AT91SAM9260EK Board. I am trying to connect the system through RJ45 Cable. And also after connecting Link Light On PC side and Device side are blinking. Device not responding to Ping.

Answer (score 0):

How are the network cables and devices connected? Did you use a hub or a switch (do they support MDI/X?). I ask, as normally you cannot simply connect two devices with a standard cable. Best is to use a small switch that support Auto-MDI/X and switches correctly to use normal or reversed cabling.

Comment: Hi Josef,     I am using Ethernet crossover cable to connect My device with PC. i am not using any Hub or Switch. I only need one to one communication.                                                             Thanks  - Rocky